# How to view the text of Itext7 com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph in Java

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm just playing around with Itext7.1.2 version. Let's say I've the following latest Itext version snippet.

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    //Initialize PDF writer
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

    //Initialize PDF document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    
    // Initialize document
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    
    LineCountingParagraph para = new LineCountingParagraph("text");
    document.add(para);                
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Text("Content1"))
            .add(" Content2");
    // Add Paragraph to document
    document.add(p);
    //Close document
    document.close();
}
```

Here I just want to view content of Paragraph i.e **Content1** and **Content2**. I read the doc of this class but I wasn't clear on getting the content of paragraph class. Let's say to display it in Sysout.out.println. 
How to I fetch it from Paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

Elements from the iText layout package may have child elements; alternatively they may be leaf elements, e.g. `Text` elements carrying text pieces.

If you want the whole text content of an element, therefore, simply recurse through its children and collect all text you visit:

```java
String getContent(IElement element) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (element instanceof Text) {
        builder.append(((Text)element).getText());
    }
    if (element instanceof IAbstractElement) {
        for (IElement child : ((IAbstractElement)element).getChildren()) {
            builder.append(getContent(child));
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

*([ParagraphContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/ParagraphContent.java#L80) method)*

In case of your example:

```java
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Text("Content1")).add(" Content2");
assertEquals("Content1 Content2", getContent(p));
```

*([ParagraphContent](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/ParagraphContent.java#L31) test `testKishoresExample`)*